# WPF DataGrid: How do you iterate in a DataGrid to get rows and columns?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, iteration, wpftoolkit

How can you iterate in the rows and columns of a **WPF DataGrid** like with a **Forms DataGridView in C#**?

For example, if you have Forms DataGridView you can do something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < formsDataGrid1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
  MessageBox.Show(formsDataGrid1.Rows[i].ToString());
  for(int j = 0; j < formsDataGrid1.Columns.Count; j++)
     MessageBox.Show(formsDataGrid1.Rows[i].Cells[j].ToString());
}
```

Thank you for any help!

### **Edit:

The reason I want to do this is that the DataGrid will be used by a user to enter certain informations in the second column of the DataGrid. Also, this DataGrid has multiple rows and I want to able to get that data and update a database with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, you don't do that : you access the underlying data source instead of the DataGrid itself. For instance, assuming the data source is an `IEnumerable<Foo>` :

```
foreach(Foo f in foos)
{
    MessageBox.Show(f.Name);
}
```

---

EDIT:

You don't need to access explicitly a specific cell of the grid : if the grid is bound to a list of objects, the object's property will be automatically updated when the user edits the corresponding cell in the grid.

Simple example with a list of contacts :

```
    public class Contact
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
    ...
    ObservableCollection<Contact> contacts = new ObservableCollection<Contact>();
    dataGrid.ItemsSource = contacts;

    ...
```

Comment: How do you get the DataSource for a WPF toolkit Datagrid?

Comment: @ThomasLevesque , actually I need to access the grid, because I have an  UserControl is a specific Column, and I need to attach an event for each element of that specific Column, you know a good way to do that? Thanks

Comment: @MBen, you can probably access a specific DataGridRow by using the ItemsContainerGenerator of the DataGrid, but from there I'm not sure how to retrieve the content of a specific column...

Comment: @ThomasLevesque Thanks ,I will try. Otherwise how would you do it? should I avoid using a custom UserControl inside my grids?

Comment: @MBen, there's a solution [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/b7299e55-92e2-4a6b-8987-869fef8f22eb/). I don't think you should avoid it, it depends on what you need to do... but usually there is no need to access the control programmatically, you can usually handle most cases with bindings, triggers etc

Comment: Thanks @ThomasLevesque, that's what I was looking for, avoid any "useless" code. I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Well I implemented a clean solution using the DataContext of the user control and binding, much much cleaner way.. Thanks @ThomasLevesque

Answer (score 7):

dg is your XAML DataGrid x:Name

```
    for (int i = 0; i < dg.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < dg.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                TextBlock cellContent = dg.Columns[j].GetCellContent(row) as TextBlock;
                Console.WriteLine(cellContent.Text);
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Grid.Column[x].GetCellContent(Row[y])` method

Comment: I take it you mean something like  `dataGridObject.Columns[x].GetCellContent( ...something... );`

But what can you enumerate over to get the `something` that goes in the parens?