# Iterate to all cells in WPF Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WPF DataGrid: How do you iterate in a DataGrid to get rows and columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295023/wpf-datagrid-how-do-you-iterate-in-a-datagrid-to-get-rows-and-columns)

I have a `WPF` `DataGrid`. I want to iterate all `cells` in `Datagrid`.
Give me a simple code to do that.
 Like this

```
for(int i =0 ....) //rows
{
    for(int j=0 ....) //columns
    {
        //access cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 public IEnumerable<Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow> GetDataGridRows(Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGrid grid)
 {
     var itemsSource = grid.ItemsSource as IEnumerable;
     if (null == itemsSource) yield return null;
     foreach (var item in itemsSource)
     {
        var row = grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow;
                if (null != row) yield return row;
      }
 }
```

//assuming that grid is bind to observable collection of some info class

```
foreach (DataGridRow rowContainer  in GetDataGridRows(gridname))
{
  if (rowContainer != null)
  {
     DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(rowContainer);

     DataGridCell cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column);
     if (cell == null)
     {
        dataGrid1.ScrollIntoView(rowContainer, dataGrid1.Columns[column]);
        cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column);
      }

      //start work with cell
  }
}
```

Comment: How to access each cell for that row inside the foreach loop?

Comment: @WPFK - if you bidnided you grid with some object observable collection tha in foreach loop you read the object associated with each row of grid tha i given in my answer liket his "Info info = (sInfo)r.Item;"

Comment: But the issue here i want to access cell property, cell's column headers etc. I cannot reach the Object binded to datagrid.

Comment: @WPFK- updated answer tried it out ..

Comment: Error: Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>' requires 1 type arguments