# WPF datagrid error: NullReferenceException, How to get data from each cell in datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, nullreferenceexception, selecteditem

I have a WPF program, to get data from a datagrid.
But this program always show error: NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code. Object reference not set to an instance of an object

What is the problem? Below is the code

```
 private string GetDatagrid(DataGrid grid)
    {
        var data = (ObservableCollection<ConfigViewModel>)grid.ItemsSource;
        StringBuilder dataStr = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
        {

            for (int j = 0; j < grid.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                TextBlock selectTextBlockInCell = grid.Columns[j].GetCellContent(data[i]) as TextBlock;

                string configVari= selectTextBlockInCell.Text; //This line comes the error!
                dataStr.Append(configVari);
                dataStr.Append("#");
            }
            dataStr.Remove(dataStr.Length - 1, 1);  
            dataStr.Append(@"\\");

        }

        return dataStr.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: This is due to the fact that you are casting `grid.Columns[j].GetCellContent(data[i]) as TextBlock`. The object you are casting to is not a `TextBlock`, so the exception is thrown when you try to access `selectTextBlockInCell`. Assuming the DataGrid is databound to some data source, you should be able to fetch what you need from the itemsource without needing to access the column elements.

Comment: Are you sure that your content is TextBlock? Maybe it is a TextBox or top-level element of a more complex template? Do not use `as` operation if you are sure that the item **must** convert correctly - use simple cast `(TextBox)grid.Columns[j].GetCellContent(data[i])`, because it won't hide or propagate an error. It will also tell what is the type of `grid.Columns[j].GetCellContent(data[i])` on exception. Also, JohnathonSullinger gives to you a very sound advice.

Comment: I don't believe the answer linked above is accurate. The OP is asking why his code is throwing a null reference exception. The issue here is how to access the elements stored within a data grid cell and why his code is throwing it, not so much "what is a null reference exception?" question.

Comment: I agree with Johnathon, the linked answer is good, but it is not the answer I want

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger Even if this question can not be considered as [solid duplicate of NRE due to specificity of the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255065/3745022), then it still does not provide enough information to understand the cause of the issue ([what is the ssce](http://sscce.org/)) and it possibly suffers from [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15686381/wpf-iterate-through-datagrid) from another SO post might do the trick.

Fetch the rows for the data grid.

```
public IEnumerable<Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow> GetDataGridRows(Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGrid grid)
{
    var itemsSource = grid.ItemsSource as IEnumerable;
    if (null == itemsSource) yield return null;
    foreach (var item in itemsSource)
    {
        var row = grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow;
        if (null != row) yield return row;
    }
}
```

Then iterate over it.

```
var rows= GetDataGridRows(nameofyordatagrid); 

foreach (DataGridRow r in rows)  
  {  
    DataRowView rv = (DataRowView)r.Item;
    foreach (DataGridColumn column in nameofyordatagrid.Columns)
    {
        if (column.GetCellContent(r) is TextBlock)
        {
            TextBlock cellContent = column.GetCellContent(r) as TextBlock;
            MessageBox.Show(cellContent.Text);
        }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Johnathon! my purpose is to get data from the datagrid cell by cell, not line by line, because i need do some modification for the data in each cell. So i need loop from the first column first row, until the last column last row, how to do it?

Comment: You have access to each cells data via the ItemsSource. If you really need to go this route, is it guaranteed each cell is a text block?

Comment: Actually I have a similar code(in the same class), it is to get data from the first column of each line, it works no problem. When I add an inner loop for each column(that is, this code), the error comes, maybe i should not use j < grid.Columns.Count? How to get column number by using ItemSource?