# How to iterate through Datagrid and create the data row in wpf?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid

I have to convert windows form control to WPF. I want to know how to iterate through Datagrid in WPF.

```
 For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In dtg.Rows
 If dr.Cells("Name").Value.ToString.Trim <> String.Empty Then
 row = dt.NewRow 'Create new row
 For cn As Integer = 0 To TotalDatagridviewColumns
 row.Item(cn) = IfNullObj(dr.Cells(cn).Value) ' This Will handle error datagridviewcell on NULL Values
 Next
 dt.Rows.Add(row)
 End If
 Next
```

I want the above mentioned to work in WPF DataGrid.

Comment: [iterate datagrid wpf](https://www.google.de/search?q=iterate+datagrid+wpf&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=pl1qV5uuBqTs8wfEwoG4Dg)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15686381/wpf-iterate-through-datagrid