# c# WPF execute query for many bases from datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have datagrid with all my basses information:
1. First column - checkbox
2.Second column - database name
3.info
4.info
I need to execute query for every checked with chekbox database.
In Winforms i do with this code :

```
  foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
  DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = item.Cells[0] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;


                if (Convert.ToBoolean(chk.Value) == true)
                {
```

and before executenonquery this line :

```
connection.ChangeDatabase(item.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
```

Can someone help me to convert to WPF version?
I need to show me second column(row) if first column(chebox) is checked.

XAML :

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="490,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="142" Width="728" SelectionChanged="dataGrid_SelectionChanged" >
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding BoolProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="CheckBox"/>
                                </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
```

This fill my dataGrid:

```
        con.server = this.server;
        con.user = this.user;
        con.password = this.password;
        con.OpenConnection();
        con.SqlQuery(Properties.Resources.databaseCatalogResource);
        DataTable dt = con.QueryEx();
        con.da.Fill(dt);
        dataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultVie
```

w;

Comment: no one can't help me ? :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15686381/wpf-iterate-through-datagrid

Comment: this help me but shows me textfields of all lines. I need to show me second row if first(chebox) is checked.

Comment: If you need logic in your datagrid, i would recommend using an observablecollection and using this as the itemsource of the datagrid. if the observablecollection is changed you can react to that with an event. In the Event method you can add/remove rows or use other logic to change the collection. the changes of the collection are automatically passed to the UI/Datagrid.

Comment: No i don't need logic. I just need to get checked row... :(

Comment: If you want to use checkbox column then look at this. also you can check if the value of the checkbox is true or false like in your example code.

Comment: oky but it's little hard for me. 

here is hard for me :
DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = item.Cells[0] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;


                if (Convert.ToBoolean(chk.Value) == true)
                {

Comment: Help me, please!

Comment: How did you set the ItemsSource property of the DataGrid and how is your XAML defined?

Comment: I edit my post and add xaml

Comment: It is still unclear how you set the ItemsSource property of fill the DataGrid with items.

Comment: Now it''s edited :)

Comment: Does your DataTable contain a column called "BoolProperty"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152036/discussion-between---and-mm8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate through the `DataView`:

```
DataView dv = dataGrid.ItemsSource as DataView;
foreach(DataRowView drv in dv)
{
    if(Convert.ToBoolean(drv["BoolProperty"]))
    {
        //row is checked...
    }
}
```

Of course your `DataTable` must contain a column called "BoolProperty" since you bind your `CheckBox` to this one. If it doesn't you need to add one:

```
con.server = this.server;
con.user = this.user;
con.password = this.password;
con.OpenConnection();
con.SqlQuery(Properties.Resources.databaseCatalogResource);
DataTable dt = con.QueryEx();
con.da.Fill(dt);
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("BoolProperty", typeof(bool))); //<---
dataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

Comment: How can set value of this column?

Comment: i try with this :
 DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["BoolProperty"] = true; 

but not work

Comment: Please ask a new question if you have another issue.