# i want to read dataGrid line by line in wpf using c#

Tags: c#, xml

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
workbook.LoadFromFile(FileNameDb);
Worksheet sheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
DataTable dataTable = sheet.ExportDataTable();
DataView view = new DataView(dataTable);
dataGridView1.ItemsSource = view;

string str;
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Items.Count - 1; i ++)
{
str = "Insert Into Sample(MCC, MNC, LAC, CellId, CellIdAddress, LAT, LONG, Network) 
                   Values(" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + ", '" + 
                              dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "'," + 
                              dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString() + "," + 
                              dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString() + "," + 
                              dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString() + "," + 
                              dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString() + "," + 
                              dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString() + "," + 
                              dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value.ToString() + ")";
    command = new SQLiteCommand(str, m_dbConnection);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

But Rows here give me error data grid does not contain a definition for Rows
and after reading every line add that line in sqlite database

Comment: Please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

the following code hopefully worked

```
foreach (DataGridCellInfo di in dgDataGrid.SelectedCells) 
{
    DataRowView dvr = (DataRowView)di.Item;

    MessageBox.Show(dvr[1].ToString()); 
}
```

Comment: must see link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15686381/wpf-iterate-through-datagrid

Answer (score 0):

using loop on datagrid like

for(int i = 0; i<=datagrid.Items.length;i++)
   {
     string name =
     ((your object) datagrid.Items[i]).name;
   }

Comment: This is just an example if you bind your wpf grid control with list <customer>have attributes name, address , location then with this you can access name row wise. And your object in this case will be customer